# Как сгруппировать и отсортировать объекты в массиве по связям между собой?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с объектами:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    relatedItemID: 3
  },
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
    relatedItemID: 1
  },
]
```

У некоторых элементов есть привязка по id к другому элементу. Нужно получить массив cо сгруппированными и отсортированными внутри групп элементами согласно их связям:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 0,
      relatedItemID: 3
    },
    {
      id: 3
      relatedItemID: 1
    },
    {id: 1}
  ],
  [{id: 2}], // на этот элемент никто не ссылается

]
```

Группы это по сути хронологическая цепь связей.
id0 ссылается на id3, по этому id3 в группе идет после id0.
id3 ссылается на id1 - по этому в группе id1 идет после id3 [id0 -> id3 -> id1].
id1 - ни на кого не ссылается, по этому он становится последним звеном в этой группе связей.
На id2 никто не ссылается, по этому он один в отдельной группе.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйтса что вы пробовали сделать

Comment: в вашем результате сортировка какая? в условии для id:0 установлена связь с третим элементом который не существует. в результате от куда взялся id:3? Так же в задаче id:1 привязана к самой себе же (у вас два элемента с id:1), а эта связь в результате потеряна, т.е. id:1 должен по логике вместе с id:2 И сортировка не логичная, даже с таким результатом должен был быть id:0, id:1 и только потом id: 3.

Comment: @Greg-- прошу прощения, там была опечатка, последний объект должен иметь id 3, а не 1 (исправил).
Я пытался в голове подобрать алгоритм (и все еще пытаюсь), пока что ничего в голову не приходит, кроме через чур запутанных способов.

Comment: А по сортировка, почему id: 3 стоит раньше id: 1? id:1 без линка, почему он не в массиве вместе с id:2.

Comment: Не понятен параметр группировки и сортировки. Попробуйте задачу поставить в виде логики ЕСЛИ (условие) ТО (группиурем или сортируем по такому -то параметру).

Comment: @Greg-- Группы это по сути хронологическая цепь связей. 
id0 ссылается на id3, по этому id3 в группе идет после id0. 

id3 ссылается на id1 - по этому в группе id1 идет после id3. 

id1 - ни на кого не ссылается, по этому он становится последним звеном в этой группе связей. 

на id2 никто не ссылается, по этому он один в отдельной группе.

Comment: т.е. одна группировка и три сортировки? Как сортировать если два элемента на один ссылаются? Очень много условий получается не понятно зачем. Зачем это делать, мне так кажется что есть путь проще чем этим заниматся?

Comment: @Greg-- Два элемента не ссылаются на один, они образуют последовательную цепь(группу), к примеру 1 ссылается на 2, а 2 на 3:
[id0 -> id3 -> id1]. Пути проще, к сожалению, нет.

Comment: попробуйте условие написать словами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу и если можно изменять исходный массив, можно попробовать так:

```js
const items1 = [
  {
    id: 0,
    relatedItemID: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    relatedItemID: 1,
  },
];

const items2 = [];

while (items1.length > 0) {
  let item = items1.shift();

  if (items1.some(({ relatedItemID }) => relatedItemID === item.id)) {
    items1.push(item);
    continue;
  }

  const group = [];
  group.push(item);
  while (item.relatedItemID !== undefined) {
    const relatedId = items1.findIndex(({ id }) => id === item.relatedItemID);
    const [related] = items1.splice(relatedId, 1);
    group.push(related);
    item = related;
  }
  items2.push(group);
}

console.log(items2);
```

Comment: Поменяйте для id0 кдюч relatedItemID на 2 и все сломалось

Comment: @Greg-- Да, вы правы. Вставил предохранитель на такой случай.

Comment: Я как понял, если мы меняем на 2 то все элементы должны быть в одной группе, это как я понял вопрос (на все элементы или ссылаются или они сами ссылаются, соответсвенно ) Но тут вопрос, после второго по последовательности должен быть id: 1 так как второй не ссылается ни на кого, потом третий, который на первый ссылается, но автор логику так и не описал, по этому хз.

Comment: Я так понял, если мы меняем на 2, то группу из id 1 и 2 и группу из id 3 и 1 ничего не связывает, поэтому они должны быть разделены.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty получилось как и должно было получиться, если заменить id0 кдюч relatedItemID на 2. id0 ссылается на id2, а id2 не имеет ссылок - группа закончилась. Следующая группа: id3 ссылается на id1, id1 ни на кого - группа закончилась.
[id0 -> id2], [id3 -> id1].

Comment: @IDigle1 То есть — подходит?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Я пока не разбирал ваш код, что бы понять, что он точно подходит, так как занимаюсь другой, более приоритетной проблемой, но в 2х вариантах массива скрипт выдал нужный результат, что уж обнадеживает, как только смогу - проверю и отмечу ваш ответ. Заранее большое вам спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty то что нужно! Еще раз спасибо)